# Hibernate: Insert query does not contain values

Tags: hibernate

Inorder to persist object to postgres db, I am using an-noted class instead of xml file. Below is the template class used.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ABCD", catalog = "XYZ", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "FILE_REF_NO") })
public class MCT112_InputFAT implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "FILE_REF_NO", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String fileRefNo;

    @Column(name = "FILE_NAME")
    private String fileName;

    @Column(name = "FILE_DATE")
    private Date fileDate;

    @Column(name = "FILE_PROCESSED_DATE")
    private Date processedDate;

    @Column(name = "PROCESSED_STATUS")
    private Boolean processedStatus;

    @Column(name = "FILLER1")
    private Date filler1;

    @Column(name = "FILLER2")
    private String filler2;

    @Column(name = "FILLER3")
    private String filler3;

    @Column(name = "FILLER4")
    private Integer filler4;

    @Column(name = "FILLER5")
    private Integer filler5;

    public MCT112_InputFAT() {

    }

    public MCT112_InputFAT(String fileRefNo, String fileName, Date fileDate, Date processedDate,
            Boolean processedStatus, Date filler1, String filler2, String filler3, Integer filler4, Integer filler5) {
        super();
        this.fileRefNo = fileRefNo;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fileDate = fileDate;
        this.processedDate = processedDate;
        this.processedStatus = processedStatus;
        this.filler1 = filler1;
        this.filler2 = filler2;
        this.filler3 = filler3;
        this.filler4 = filler4;
        this.filler5 = filler5;
    }

    public String getFileRefNo() {
        return fileRefNo;
    }

    public void setFileRefNo(String fileRefNo) {
        this.fileRefNo = fileRefNo;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public Date getFileDate() {
        return fileDate;
    }

    public void setFileDate(Date fileDate) {
        this.fileDate = fileDate;
    }

    public Date getProcessedDate() {
        return processedDate;
    }

    public void setProcessedDate(Date processedDate) {
        this.processedDate = processedDate;
    }

    public Boolean getProcessedStatus() {
        return processedStatus;
    }

    public void setProcessedStatus(Boolean processedStatus) {
        this.processedStatus = processedStatus;
    }

    public Date getFiller1() {
        return filler1;
    }

    public void setFiller1(Date filler1) {
        this.filler1 = filler1;
    }

    public String getFiller2() {
        return filler2;
    }

    public void setFiller2(String filler2) {
        this.filler2 = filler2;
    }

    public String getFiller3() {
        return filler3;
    }

    public void setFiller3(String filler3) {
        this.filler3 = filler3;
    }

    public Integer getFiller4() {
        return filler4;
    }

    public void setFiller4(Integer filler4) {
        this.filler4 = filler4;
    }

    public Integer getFiller5() {
        return filler5;
    }

    public void setFiller5(Integer filler5) {
        this.filler5 = filler5;
    }

}`
```

But while running the values are populated as empty in the sql string as below.

```
insert into XYZ.ABCD(FILE_NAME, FILE_DATE, FILE_PROCESSED_DATE, PROCESSED_STATUS, FILLER1, FILLER2, FILLER3, FILLER4, FILLER5, FILE_REF_NO) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Does anybody know what is problem here.

Answer (score 1):

By default Hibernate use a basic logging feature (with show_sql property enabled) which does not display request parameters.

If you need request parameter you must use log4j library and put **logger log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type** to **TRACE** level.

See below an example of log4j.properties (for log4j 1.2):

```
# Send log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Display only startup messages
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
# same as show_sql=true
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

# display bind parameter
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```